# Handling nested state with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set up a URL structure like :

`http://example.com/quote/:param1/user/:param2/details`

But when i'm trying to navigate to the ending state, i'm redirected to the first one with the wrong param.

Here are my states :

```
.state('quote', {
    url: '/quote',
    ...
})

.state('quote.detail', {
    url: '/:quoteId',
    ...
})

.state('quote.detail.user', {
    url: '/user/:userId',
    abstract: true
})

.state('quote.detail.user.detail', {
    url: '/details',
    ...
})
```

So basically, I can reach my `quote.detail.user.detail` state by going to

`http://exemple.com/quote/1/user/12/details`

or `$state.go('quote.detail.user.detail', {quoteId: 1, userId: 12})`

But unfortunately, I'm redirected to the second declared state (`quote.detail`) with
`$stateParams.quoteId =  1/user/12/details`

It look like ui-router don't detect the end of my param...

There is something i'm doing wrong ? Or can achieve the behaviour I want ?

Comment: I created a STACKBLITZ with your code (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-kucgkz?file=home%2Fhome.config.js) and everything seems to work as expected there, please try to reproduce your issue on my code (fork it) and I will try to help...